# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему используя transform-style: preserve-3d; в примере есть мигание и как от него избавиться?

Tags: css-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему используя transform-style: preserve-3d; в примере есть мигание и как от него избавиться? <https://codepen.io/html5book/pen/bOLzVq    >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу сказать с уверенностью в 100%, но возможно это дефект перспективы. Что бы решить, достаточно указать браузеру что бы не дотягивал до конца.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  perspective: 500px;
  margin: 0 40px;
  background: rgba(195, 209, 212, .7);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.style-flat {
  transform-style: flat;
}

.style-3d {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip {
  height: 160px;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(169, 90, 145, .8);
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s infinite;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0.1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p><kbd>transform-style: flat;</kbd></p>
  <div class="container style-flat">
    <div class="flip"></div>
  </div>
  <p><kbd>transform-style: preserve-3d;</kbd></p>
  <div class="container style-3d">
    <div class="flip"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

И да такие штуки лучше тестировать в других браузерах... с анимацией бывают проблемы

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли